# Can't go through Writing your First Application tutorial with Java chaincode with Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.3

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

after following successfully "Building Your First Network" tutorial on javascript and "Writing Your First Application" tutorial on the default language, I am getting an error when I try to execute it with java:

```
./startFabric.sh java
```

It's important as my project will be developed both chaincode and client on Java.

The error is when script tries to instantiate the smart contract on the channel. Previous commands execute OK:

```
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 1
```

I have tried similar steps based on BYFN scripts and I have everything working for java chaincode as long as I extend ChaincodeBase class. If I implement ContractInterface, I get described error too when using BYFN. Is there any special action when activating java chaincode using ContractInterface I should consider? (Note that it's failing for me with my custom classes in BYFN tutorial and also runnning plain standard "Writing Your First Application" tutorial. May there be a problem with that Java types on 1.4.3?)

Full output of command generating error (I have enabled DEBUG in docker-compose-cli.yaml file of BYFN tutorial, used in this other tutorial):

```
+ echo 'Instantiating smart contract on mychannel'
Instantiating smart contract on mychannel
+ docker exec -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp cli peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n fabcar -l java -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[]}' -P 'AND('\''Org1MSP.member'\'','\''Org2MSP.member'\'')' --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
2019-10-05 20:53:15.020 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 001 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP
2019-10-05 20:53:15.021 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 002 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11
2019-10-05 20:53:15.022 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 003 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-10-05 20:53:15.028 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 004 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Label setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-10-05 20:53:15.028 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 005 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-10-05 20:53:15.029 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 006 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Pin setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-10-05 20:53:15.030 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 007 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-10-05 20:53:15.031 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 008 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Hash setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-10-05 20:53:15.031 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 009 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-10-05 20:53:15.032 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00a Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Security setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-10-05 20:53:15.033 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00b Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.FileKeyStore
2019-10-05 20:53:15.033 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00c Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-10-05 20:53:15.034 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00d Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.FileKeyStore.KeyStore setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-10-05 20:53:15.035 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00e Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-10-05 20:53:15.036 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00f Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Library setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-10-05 20:53:15.037 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 010 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: invalid character 'S' looking for beginning of value
2019-10-05 20:53:15.037 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 011 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.Default setting to string SW
2019-10-05 20:53:15.038 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 012 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.SW
2019-10-05 20:53:15.038 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 013 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: invalid character 'S' looking for beginning of value
2019-10-05 20:53:15.038 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 014 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.Hash setting to string SHA2
2019-10-05 20:53:15.039 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 015 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: 256
2019-10-05 20:53:15.039 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 016 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.Security setting to int 256
2019-10-05 20:53:15.040 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 017 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.SW.FileKeyStore
2019-10-05 20:53:15.040 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 018 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: unexpected end of JSON input
2019-10-05 20:53:15.040 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 019 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.FileKeyStore.KeyStore setting to string 
2019-10-05 20:53:15.040 UTC [viperutil] EnhancedExactUnmarshalKey -> DEBU 01a map[peer.BCCSP:map[PKCS11:map[Label:<nil> Pin:<nil> Hash:<nil> Security:<nil> FileKeyStore:map[KeyStore:<nil>] Library:<nil>] Default:SW SW:map[FileKeyStore:map[KeyStore:] Hash:SHA2 Security:256]]]
2019-10-05 20:53:15.049 UTC [bccsp_sw] openKeyStore -> DEBU 01b KeyStore opened at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore]...done
2019-10-05 20:53:15.050 UTC [bccsp] initBCCSP -> DEBU 01c Initialize BCCSP [SW]
2019-10-05 20:53:15.051 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01d Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts
2019-10-05 20:53:15.054 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01e Inspecting file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem
2019-10-05 20:53:15.057 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01f Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts
2019-10-05 20:53:15.074 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 020 Inspecting file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
2019-10-05 20:53:15.078 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 021 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/admincerts
2019-10-05 20:53:15.081 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 022 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/intermediatecerts
2019-10-05 20:53:15.082 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 023 Intermediate certs folder not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/intermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/intermediatecerts: no such file or directory]
2019-10-05 20:53:15.082 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 024 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts
2019-10-05 20:53:15.084 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 025 Inspecting file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
2019-10-05 20:53:15.087 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 026 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts
2019-10-05 20:53:15.088 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 027 TLS intermediate certs folder not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts: no such file or directory]
2019-10-05 20:53:15.088 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 028 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/crls
2019-10-05 20:53:15.089 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 029 crls folder not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/crls]. Skipping. [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/crls: no such file or directory]
2019-10-05 20:53:15.092 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 02a Loading NodeOUs
2019-10-05 20:53:15.101 UTC [msp] newBccspMsp -> DEBU 02b Creating BCCSP-based MSP instance
2019-10-05 20:53:15.101 UTC [msp] New -> DEBU 02c Creating Cache-MSP instance
2019-10-05 20:53:15.101 UTC [msp] loadLocaMSP -> DEBU 02d Created new local MSP
2019-10-05 20:53:15.101 UTC [msp] Setup -> DEBU 02e Setting up MSP instance Org1MSP
2019-10-05 20:53:15.101 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 02f Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2019-10-05 20:53:15.101 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 030 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2019-10-05 20:53:15.103 UTC [bccsp_sw] loadPrivateKey -> DEBU 031 Loading private key [1213fbf8cd9319e6818538fcdac1e85754eca7a67e5edfa08b6bf776a36eb509] at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/1213fbf8cd9319e6818538fcdac1e85754eca7a67e5edfa08b6bf776a36eb509_sk]...
2019-10-05 20:53:15.106 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 032 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICKjCCAdCgAwIBAgIRAOKj1RX6UST5URhwxCLpuGwwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwczEL
MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDVNhbiBG
cmFuY2lzY28xGTAXBgNVBAoTEG9yZzEuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20xHDAaBgNVBAMTE2Nh
Lm9yZzEuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20wHhcNMTkxMDA1MjA0NzAwWhcNMjkxMDAyMjA0NzAw
WjBrMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMN
U2FuIEZyYW5jaXNjbzEOMAwGA1UECxMFYWRtaW4xHzAdBgNVBAMMFkFkbWluQG9y
ZzEuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20wWTATBgcqhkjOPQIBBggqhkjOPQMBBwNCAAR/gLdyUdjv
nfpc3a6AwB8a7rl3JyVX+MOjjqbgpLC3WCr/2PP7ruc9eykCBIldbYFjT5cmHSBx
gyRrwdaHKmewo00wSzAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCB4AwDAYDVR0TAQH/BAIwADArBgNV
HSMEJDAigCDVsUe8vAO3KUVLi9k3fFC1lOKAcof29iGCfW/FL+Af2zAKBggqhkjO
PQQDAgNIADBFAiEA68aYxGYh25KTsVL80q7Ije6IEJDLy7j19sTgbLrkvSECIEg9
L5Xolh50rmr9FUzGbrVZ1EXwrCUPlVj1JuGOuJhf
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2019-10-05 20:53:15.107 UTC [msp] setupSigningIdentity -> DEBU 033 Signing identity expires at 2029-10-02 20:47:00 +0000 UTC
2019-10-05 20:53:15.114 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 034 parsed scheme: ""
2019-10-05 20:53:15.114 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 035 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2019-10-05 20:53:15.115 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 036 ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{peer0.org1.example.com:7051 0  <nil>}]
2019-10-05 20:53:15.115 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 037 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2019-10-05 20:53:15.115 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 038 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0001fe630, CONNECTING
2019-10-05 20:53:15.122 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 039 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0001fe630, READY
2019-10-05 20:53:15.131 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 03a parsed scheme: ""
2019-10-05 20:53:15.131 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 03b scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2019-10-05 20:53:15.133 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 03c ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{peer0.org1.example.com:7051 0  <nil>}]
2019-10-05 20:53:15.134 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 03d ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2019-10-05 20:53:15.135 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03e pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0002701a0, CONNECTING
2019-10-05 20:53:15.141 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03f pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0002701a0, READY
2019-10-05 20:53:15.146 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 040 Obtaining default signing identity
2019-10-05 20:53:15.151 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 041 parsed scheme: ""
2019-10-05 20:53:15.151 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 042 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2019-10-05 20:53:15.151 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 043 ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{orderer.example.com:7050 0  <nil>}]
2019-10-05 20:53:15.152 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 044 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2019-10-05 20:53:15.153 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 045 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0001c6ff0, CONNECTING
2019-10-05 20:53:15.161 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 046 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0001c6ff0, READY
2019-10-05 20:53:15.163 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 047 Using default escc
2019-10-05 20:53:15.163 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 048 Using default vscc
2019-10-05 20:53:15.167 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 049 Sign: plaintext: 0ABE070A6608031A0B08BB85E4EC0510...324D53500A04657363630A0476736363 
2019-10-05 20:53:15.167 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 04a Sign: digest: F54E5852AADCA181D55B7C517AFC1E292D1A59CB19AB0B37EAED68244A4A0190 
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 1
```

Comment: first stop the network, stop all running containers, remove them, restart your docker, then initiate the script ./startFabric.sh as it is, without "java"----

Comment: The thing people most often forget to do is clean up the volumes. Easiest way is to always make sure you do a `./byfn.sh down`

Comment: Thanks, I have tried both and all my java chaincode works as long as I don'tuse the Contract Interface. The problem seems to be that type of chaincode.

Comment: (If I startFabric.sh without Java it starts with go language. All this issue is about Java chaincode)

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the sample-version for Hyperledger Fabric 2.0 ([link](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples)) and retry to run startFabric.sh command with Java 1.8.

It works for me.